# Proof for Schwarz Inequality- Inner Product Space

Tags: functional-analysis, inner-products

I am trying to understand proof of Schwarz Inequality for inner product spaces. The proof as given in "Functional Analysis" by BV Limaye on page 369 is attached. I am unable to understand the expansion of the marked step, and the last line of attached text. Would be grateful for an easy explanation!

[image]

Comment: $(ax+by,ax+by)=(ax,ax+by)+(by,ax+by)=(ax,ax)+(ax,by)+(by,ax)+(by,by)=a\overline{a}(x,x)+a\overline{b}(x,y)+b\overline{a}(y,x)+b\overline{b}(y,y)$ using exclusively the sesquilinearity. Use it with $a=(y,y)$ and $b=-(x,y)$.

Comment: what step is unclear?

Comment: @conditionalMethod..Thank you...understood now